# The Mean of a multivariate function

Tags: probability

Jane and Jack each toss a fair coin twice.
Let X be the number of heads Jane obtains.
Let Y be ther number of heads Jack obtains.
Define U = X + Y.
Find the mean and variance of U.

I have tried to first find f(U) and am unable to.
Would it be:
$$ {4 \choose u}(0.5)^{u}(0.5)^{4-u}  $$

Thank you!

Comment: Yes your $f(U)$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $P(U=u)$ is correct. Here is a hint, but I encourage you to do the problem your way too, it would be an instructive exercise.

**Hint:**

$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$